# Did I get this EF Core 2.0 "loading related data" methodology correct?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

The database relationships for a scenario where a Publisher publishes Books that are written by Authors who are exclusively signed to the publisher but may have several pen names:

```
A Publisher has many Books
A Publisher has many SignedAuthors
A SignedAuthor has one AuthorDetails (one AuthorDetails:many SignedAuthors)
```

The SignedAuthor records the pen name used to write the book, (so a book has a SignedAuthor, not an AuthorDetails) whereas the AuthorDetails are the real details for the author

I wasn't initially aware that EF Core doesn't lazy load. I first did this:

```
for(var pub in _dbContext.Publishers.Where(p => p.Name = "Penguin"))
  //code
```

And then subsequently found that they never seemed to have any books..

Then I later would try an "explicit load":

```
_dbContext.Entry(pub).Collection(p => p.Books).Load();
```

Which worked fine, but I struggled with understanding how then to load the author stuff in one go. It seemed I could do this:

```
_dbContext.Entry(pub).Collection(p => p.SignedAuthors).Load();
```

But I wasn't sure how to get the AuthorDetails to come along with it. If I tried to load every one individually, surely that would be battering the database with queries, selecting one row at a time via the PK:

```
//do for every signedauthor already loaded
_dbContext.Entry(signedauthor).Reference(sa => sa.AuthorDetail).Load();
```

So I scrapped the whole lot and instead wrote this to "eager load" everything I wanted to use:

```
         var pubs = 
            _dbContext.Publishers
              .Where(p => p.Name = "Penguin")
                .Include(e => e.Books)
                .Include(e => e.SignedAuthors)
                  .ThenInclude(e => e.AuthorDetails);
```

It works fine; I've no idea how many SQLs it entails, though I'd like to think it's just one (pub JOIN book JOIN signedauthors JOIN authordetails)

Question 1) is this the correct form to "eager load" all the data I want to use? Does it assemble just one SQL query with several joins?

Question 2) how should I have performed the "explicit loading" directly, in a performant way, particularly the join between SignedAuthors and Authors?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data didn't seem to indicate there's a way to load a collection and all of the single detail entities hanging off each collection entry, in one hit..

Comment: One way to see how this is being formed is to run sql profiler, this will show you what this gets interpreted into,

Comment: Having put a quick logger in, I was somewhat surprised to learn that 3 queries are used for the eager version, essentially: `SELECT Publishers`, `SELECT Publishers JOIN Books` and `SELECT Publishers JOIN SignedAuthors JOIN AuthorDetails` each time with the same WHERE clause on Publishers. I suppose it prevents cartesian products and mismatched joins from screwing the dataset up..